# How to achieve this layout with same color scheme in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, flutter-layout

I want to develop the Following design in Flutter, I am using Flutter default colors, the I am facing is that when I use Container having color is black and then want to place some Widgets inside of that container having Lighter color than Black as you can in Following image are not visible how to resolve this?

[image]

Here is some **Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:marshal/Payment.dart';

import 'bottomnavigationbar.dart';

class Payment2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Payment2State createState() => _Payment2State();
}

class _Payment2State extends State<Payment2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PaymentButton = Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Colors.red,
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () {
          Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Paymentdone());
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
        },
        child: Text("Payment",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: style.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Payment"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "ENTER YOUR CARD DETAILS",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16),
            ),
            Card(
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(),
                title: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "MasterCard",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '90 \u0024',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: emailField(),
            ),
//
//            Row(
//                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
//                children: <Widget>[
//                  Card(
//                    child: Exp_Date(),
//                  ),
//                  Card(
//                    child: CVV(),
//                  )
//                ],
//              ),
            TextField(
              style: style,
              maxLength: 5,
              cursorColor: Colors.red,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'MM/YY',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    width: 0,
                    style: BorderStyle.none,
                  ),
                ),
                filled: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              ),
            ),
//            Exp_Date(),
            PaymentButton,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(),
    );
  }

  Widget emailField() {
    return TextFormField(
      //obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0, 0, 10.0),
        //labelText: "Card Number",
        hintText: 'xxxx xxxx 1234',
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget Exp_Date() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0, 0, 10.0),
        // labelText: "Exp Date",
        hintText: "MM/YY",
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget CVV() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0, 0, 10.0),
        //labelText: "CVV",
        hintText: "CVV",
      ),
    );
  }

  TextStyle style =
      TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0);
}
```

**Note**

I don't have any issues with BottomNavigationBar

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm trying to understand your question, but I don't get it. What is not visible?

Comment: There are three colors in this Activity Red, black, and Black26(light black). the light black one is not visible.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous what is it that you want to show? and it is not showing?

Comment: As for me, I can see the three colors mentioned above, what exactly are you expecting ? What did you get instead ? @QasimAli

Comment: the shown Screenshot is my desired output, but its not, The lighter black color is not visible while I run my code

Comment: I still don't get it. When I try your widget you can clearly see (although the app I quickly tested it in overrides the red app bar with our coloring) the colors you applied. There is no "light black" though, but the blueGray and it's clearly visible, where you applied it (it's missing on the "MM/YY" text field, though).

Comment: black26 is not a light black. It's a black with 26% opacity.

Comment: Actually ,code maybe somehow Edited, I just want the above design to be built, i tried it many times but failed to develop same thing.

Comment: Thanks @Mobina for stating to obvious. I was just simplifying, obviously.

Comment: I was mentioning it for the OP as he wants to put a widget with black26 color on a widget with black color, which will cause the first widget to be transparent. @dzim

Comment: @Mobina Ah OK, sorry. ;-) Now I finally understood the underlaying problem: Well, putting black with an opacity on a black background is not very sensible. I'd go with the answer shafayat-hossain has provided, since his color doesn't have any transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Color(0xFF1E1E1E)` instead of `Colors.blueGrey`.

Comment: this is working fine, How can I use two Widgets * TextFields" containing hints "MM/YY and CVV" in the same Row?

Comment: You've given answer in your comment. Put those `TextField`s in a `Row`. It should work.

Comment: In same Row TextFields are not Working?